# Combining broadcast and boolean array indexing in Numpy for image masking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I am working on an image processing/building problem. I have a smaller image that I want to place into a larger one. As normal the image is represented as a 3d array. This works fine with the following code (both `element_pixels` and `image_pixels` are 3d ndarrays with depth 3 representing RGB, `element_pixels` is equal to or smaller than `image_pixels` in the other dimensions):

```
        element_pixels = element.get_pixels()
        image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :] = element_pixels
```

However I want to treat black pixels in the element as transparent. The simplest way to do this seems to be to mask the element so I don't modify image_pixels where element_pixel is black. I tried the following, but I am tying myself in knots:

```
        element_pixels = element.get_pixels()
        b = np.all(element_pixels == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
        black_pixels_mask = np.dstack([b,b,b])
        image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :][black_pixels_mask] = element_pixels
```

This looks to be correctly generating a mask but I can't figure out how to use it. I get the following error:

> image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :][black_pixels_mask] = element_pixels
> TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 3 dimensions

The masking kind-of works (i.e. runs without exceptions) if I replace the final `= element_pixels` with a constant, but I'm struggling to extrapolate this to a solution.

**Extra detail of sizes**

```
element_pixels.shape=(40, 40,3)
image_pixels.shape=(100, 100,3)

image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :].shape = (40,40,3)
```

**A MRE in 2d**
This captures what I'm trying to do without the complexity of the extra dimension.

```
import numpy as np

bg = np.ones((10,10))*0.5
img = np.concatenate([np.zeros((5,1)),np.ones((5,1))], axis=1)

mask = img == 0
# copy the *non-zero* pixel values of img to a particular location in bg
bg[5:10,5:7][mask] = img # this throws exception

print(bg)
```

Comment: To make understanding easier, describe the variables.  `black_pixels_mask.shape`?  `image_pixels.shape`?  `image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :].shape`?  The problem step is that last `temp[mask]=...`

Comment: Added to question, check out the MRE I added for a more concise 2d example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered after some experimentation that the (perhaps obvious in hindsight) answer is the *you have to apply the mask to both sides*.

So taking my MRE:

```
import numpy as np

bg = np.ones((10,10))*0.5
img = np.concatenate([np.zeros((5,1)),np.ones((5,1))], axis=1)
mask = img > 0

bg[5:10,5:7][mask] = img[mask]

print(bg)
```

Or going back to my original code, the only line that changes is:

```
image_pixels[element.position[0]:element.position[0]+element.height, element.position[1]:element.position[1]+element.width, :][~black_pixels_mask] = element_pixels[~black_pixels_mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a 2d mask on a 3d array. So something like this will replace all black pixels of `img` with those of `background`.

```py
img = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10, 3))
background = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10, 3))
mask = np.all(img == [0,0,0], axis=2)
img[mask] = background[img]
```

I'm not sure I understand what is in `image_pixels` but I think you can do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my issue seems to be because I am using both the mask and the [: , : , :] style index togther. Both the _pixels variables and ndarrays - I'll add that to my question.